# how to save a button

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to save this button so that when i close the browser and reopen it i still is white.
I tried a lot but i just don't get the solution.

```
<script>
    function save(){

    var storeButton = document.getElementById("testButton1");
    localStorage.setItem("button", storeButton)

}

function load(){

var storedButton = localStorage.getItem("button");
if(storedButton){

    document.getElementById("testButton1") = storedButton;

}

}


 </script>

 <body onload="load()">
 <input class="blue" type="button" id="testButton1" value="click me to turn white" style="background-color:blue" onclick="changeBlue(this)">
 <input type="button" id="testButton" value="Save" onclick="save()"/>

</body>
```

Comment: You can only store string values in localStorage. Save the actual color as a value and apply it on load (if it exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save the button itself since local storage only stores strings.

Instead, save the information that you need in the form of a string (in this case, the color):

```
function save() {
  var storeButton = document.getElementById("testButton1");
  localStorage.setItem("buttonColor", storeButton.style.backgroundColor);
}

function load() {
  var color = localStorage.getItem("buttonColor");
  if (color) {
    document.getElementById("testButton1").style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

Comment: And how can i do this with more buttons?

Comment: Use another key instead of "buttonColor" for your other buttons. You could use the same key as the id for your button for example, so the above would be "testButton1".